# Docker adminer не работает

Tags: docker

Недавно начал изучать докер. Пока пробую простые образы с докер хаба. Возникла проблема: устанавливаю образы mariadb + adminer, делаю docker run по инструкции из документаций.

Для mariadb:

```
$ docker run --detach --name serverdb --env MARIADB_USER=user --env MARIADB_PASSWORD=123 --env MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123-pw  mariadb:10.7-focal
```

Для adminer:

```
$ docker run --link serverdb:db -p 8080:8080 adminer:4-standalone
```

Перехожу на localhost:8080 и просто "не удается получить доступ к сайту"

Все отрабатывает без ошибок, смотрел логи - они тоже чистые

Использую последнюю версию docker-toolbox, возможно дело в этом, но и версии образов далеко не самые свежие.

```
Docker version 19.03.1, Docker Client 19.03.1, Docker Engine 19.03.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно ввести команду `$ docker-machine ip default`, ввести полученный ip адрес:порт в строку браузера и в таком случае будет запущен adminer + db в браузере.